# change a variable in a nested function

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to change a variable in a nested function, it's a lot of code so here is a simplified build up of the JS file

```
var time = 0;

$("button").click(function(){
    time = time + 1
});

function thisIsTheTime(){
    clockDesign()   
    // big bunch of variables and more code
}

function clockDesign(){

  ProgressIndicator: {
   name: "ProgressIndicator",
   element: create_element_with_attributes("div", {
      innerHTML:
      "<div class='ProgressbarContainer' style='text-align: center;'>
      + time
      + </div>"
      })
   }

}
```

what i try to achieve is the following, update the time  - each time a person clicks the button - in the second function ClockDesign() However this is rendered directly when the page loads. it keeps the 0.

Comment: You've declared `var time` outside those functions, so you can access and modify `time` from anywhere. Please post valid code that reproduces the problem, a [mre]. I suspect the problem here is that you expect the progress to magically update because you've changed the value of `time`; that's not going to happen. You have to manually update the HTML yourself.

Comment: How about add a line in the click event and update the content of the div?

Comment: Where is clockDesign() being called?

Answer (score 2):

You can try updating your click event with this -

```
        $("button").click(function(){
            time = time + 1
            $(".ProgressbarContainer").text(time);
        });
```